# Solve For Variable Inside Natural Log and Outside

Tags: logarithms

So, the equation I have is more simplified on here compared to the one I have to solve but here it is:

$$10 = 2 \cdot \dfrac{x+4}{5x} \cdot \ln\left(\dfrac{2x}{6}\right)$$

I am unfamiliar with how to solve for a variable that is inside a natural logarithm and outside of it.

Comment: Please make the question self-contained by typing up the question, then show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Plotting a graph might help

Comment: You cannot do it analytically and get x = in terms of elementary functions. You need a numerical method.